# send json object using http post method for android application

Tags: android

i am trying to send JSON object to my php webservice.

I have referred this url :- http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/

In my web service,  I have to pass username and password but i don't know,

what is the  GSON. can you tell why GSON use in this.????

I am new in json. if you know about json please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a Java library to convert java objects to JSON and vice-versa. You don't need it unless you have some complex JSON structure. For simple objects you can easily construct the JSON string yourself.