# send json object using http post method for android application

Tags: android

This is my web service Login url :- http://www.cricutchecklist.com/iphone/login.php

i have to pass username and password.

do you  have android correct code for sending this two parameter perfectly?

```
username- chandreshkanetiya
password- 9375051117
```

php webservice parameter is username and password.

My code always returned me :- `{"response" : {"success":false,"error":{"code":2,"description":"Incorrect script parameters"}}}` if i pass correct username and password.

i am expecting this:-- `{"response" : {"success":true,"error":{"code":2,"description":"Incorrect script parameters"}}}`

if you solve this problem let me know.
thank you.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862207/send-json-object-using-http-post-method-for-android-application)

Comment: whats your parametername for username and password which you attching with url

Comment: parametername are ("username","chandreshkanetiya") and ("password","9375051117") till if you have query let me know.